# Azure Functions Service to Service: Application is not assign to a role

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-authentication, azure-service-runtime

I am trying to set up a service with azure functions so that other special app registrations can call it and  have special access to read anything.  I'm just starting, so I thought I would have my service simply authenticate against itself like this:

```
var myAppId = "8d87ba47-3b51-4e24-a790-a966a0130ceb";
var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(Settings.AadTenant, false);
var clientAssertionCertificate = new ClientAssertionCertificate(myAppId, ApplicationCertificate);
return authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(myAppId, clientAssertionCertificate).Result.AccessToken;
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

```
Application '8d87ba47-3b51-4e24-a790-a966a0130ceb' is not assigned to a role for the application '8d87ba47-3b51-4e24-a790-a966a0130ceb'.
```

I know I've got everything wired up right because the tenant recognizes all of the Id's, so the problem is likely in my App Registration's manifest.  But I think I have set up my app's manifest correctly:

```
"appId": "8d87ba47-3b51-4e24-a790-a966a0130ceb",
"appRoles": [
    {
        "allowedMemberTypes": [ "Application" ],
        "description": "Some services can have global access",
        "displayName": "ProductivityService Auth",
        "id": "8d87ba47-3b51-4e24-a790-a966a0130ceb",
        "isEnabled": true,
        "value": "GlobalReadAccess"
    }
],
```

I am at a loss of what to do at this point.  I'm not exactly sure what should go in the "value" parameter, but I cannot find any details information about the parameters inside "appRoles" and the examples I've found are geared to authorizing users. I've tried "Reader" and "Writer" but same result.  Ideas?

Comment: I am not sure if the app can a have a role on itself. It fails because the app permission is not granted to it.

Comment: I mean, another application registered in the directory could require that app permission, and then get tokens and call it.

Comment: @Juunas, You may be right, but seems weird that an app can't access itself, especially since several different services could use the same App identity.   It's also super inconvenient to have to create a new App registration to properly develop and test this code.